# It is possible to replace a flat.vmdk file with a older backup version of the file?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vmdk

We have an vmware (6.0) machine that uses vmdk-files. There are `flat.vmdk` and delta.vmdk files.
The files are dated with 27.05.2021. As far as I know, the `flat.vmdk` are read only and did not get changed, the changes are written in the `delta.vmdk` files.

Now we have the problem that the `flat.vmdk` file is corrupt. We have a backup of this `flat.vmdk` file from 18.05.2021.

Files of the vm machine:

```
29.05.2021  09:26    <DIR>          .
29.05.2021  09:26    <DIR>          ..
18.05.2021  17:57       168.054.784 disk0249163481-000001-delta.vmdk
27.05.2021  15:50               332 disk0249163481-000001.vmdk
29.05.2021  09:26         4.456.064 disk0249163481-000002-ctk.vmdk
27.05.2021  12:49     2.483.310.592 disk0249163481-000002-delta.vmdk
27.05.2021  12:49               439 disk0249163481-000002.vmdk
18.05.2021  17:56   145.999.527.936 disk0249163481-flat.vmdk
18.05.2021  17:56               477 disk0249163481.vmdk
18.05.2021  17:56         1.908.736 disk3989547843-000001-delta.vmdk
27.05.2021  15:50               333 disk3989547843-000001.vmdk
29.05.2021  09:26         7.614.568 disk3989547843-000002-ctk.vmdk
27.05.2021  12:49    53.957.435.392 disk3989547843-000002-delta.vmdk
27.05.2021  12:49               440 disk3989547843-000002.vmdk
18.05.2021  17:56   997.989.285.888 disk3989547843-flat.vmdk
27.05.2021  15:50               479 disk3989547843.vmdk
27.05.2021  15:50             9.877 UDPIVM_EXSERVER-Snapshot1.vmsn
18.05.2021  18:06             9.891 UDPIVM_EXSERVER-Snapshot2.vmsn
27.05.2021  12:50            74.232 UDPIVM_EXSERVER.nvram
27.05.2021  15:50             1.225 UDPIVM_EXSERVER.vmsd
27.05.2021  15:50             2.730 UDPIVM_EXSERVER.vmx
27.05.2021  15:50             3.763 UDPIVM_EXSERVER.vmxf
27.05.2021  13:40           108.333 vmware-10test.log
27.05.2021  16:09           108.420 vmware-15.log
27.05.2021  16:21           108.335 vmware-16.log
27.05.2021  17:07           108.333 vmware-17.log
27.05.2021  18:59           108.418 vmware-18.log
27.05.2021  19:32           108.335 vmware-19.log
27.05.2021  20:25           108.417 vmware-20.log
29.05.2021  09:26           108.418 vmware.log
              28 Datei(en), 1.200.612.565.187 Bytes
               2 Verzeichnis(se), 5.433.943.818.240 Bytes frei
```

Files that neet do replaced with:

```
29.05.2021  12:14   145.999.527.936 disk0249163481-flat.vmdk
29.05.2021  12:15   997.989.285.888 disk3989547843-flat.vmdk
```

It is possible to replace only the corrupt flat.vmdk with the older version?
If yes, have someone an tutorial or instructions how to do?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to mix new **delta.vmdk** files with an old **flat.vmdk** file.
We just copied them in the same folder and read in the VM via configfile.

The VM is working.